# Issue with Work-Change in KE equivalence

Tags: work

First-year physics student, with a pretty basic question.

I've seen proofs that Work = Change in Kinetic Energy involving calculus, and they make sense to me, but I'm not sure why the following, much simpler and less general form doesn't work:

Assuming the angle between force and distance = 0, and that the force is constant:

$$W = F \cdot d = Fd = mad = m \Delta (v/t)d = m \Delta((d/t)/t)d = m \Delta (d^2/t^2) = \Delta mv^2 = 2 \Delta KE $$, which is twice what it should be. This is a very simplified case, so I'm not sure what the source of the trouble I'm having is.

Comment: $W = \int F \mathrm{d}s$, not $W = F\cdot s$ is the proper definition of work.

Comment: But assuming the force is constant, isn't $$ F \cdot s $$ equivalent?

Comment: You're right, that's not the error. What is going on with your $\Delta$-notation, though? The steps between $mad$ and $\Delta m v^2$ are totally non-obvious, and the $d$ seems to disappear and reappear.

Comment: Fixed the Case of the Disappearing D, which was an accidental omission on my part, but not sure what you mean about the delta notation -- is it just that I can't use the formatting properly, or is that somehow where my problem is coming from?

Comment: I just don't really know what $\Delta(v/t)$ is supposed to be. Do you mean that acceleration is change in distance divided by change in time, more commonly written $a = \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$? If yes, then the issue is the reverse of what I thought first - the proper definition of acceleration is as a *derivative*, and for a constant acceleration, the distance is quadratic in time, so $\frac{\Delta d}{\Delta t} \neq \frac{\mathrm{d}d}{\mathrm{d}t}$!

Comment: @ACuriousMind that would probably make a pretty good answer (perhaps in combination with your previous comment)

Comment: @DavidZ: I realized that shortly after I'd written it. It will be done.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yeah, that's it. Could you elaborate on your last sentence? I'm not sure I follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposing that the acceleration $a$, which is the second derivative of the distance $s$ (I don't use $d$ because $\mathrm{d}d$ looks awful),

$$ a = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2s}{\mathrm{d}t^2}$$

can be written as

$$ a = \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t} = \frac{\Delta(\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t})}{\Delta t} = \frac{\Delta^2 s}{\Delta t^2}$$

which simply doesn't work (and $\Delta^2$ isn't properly defined, anyway).

For constant $a$, $s(t) = s_0 + v_0t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$ and $v(t) = v_0 + at$, so $a = \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t} = \frac{a\Delta t}{\Delta t} = a$ indeed works. This is because the dependence of $v$ on $t$ is *linear*, so the slope of $v(t)$ is the same at every point.

On the contrary, $s$ is quadratic in $t$, and (let $s_0 = v_0 = 0$ for simplicity)

$$ v \overset{?}{=} \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t} = \frac{\frac{a}{2}((t + \Delta t)^2 - t^2)}{\Delta t} = \frac{at\Delta t + \frac{a}{2}(\Delta t)^2}{\Delta t} = at + \frac{a}{2}\Delta t$$

is off by $\frac{a}{2}\Delta t$ from being the correct velocity. (Note that the limit $\Delta t \to 0$ would give the correct answer - this would turn the quotient by $\Delta t$ into the proper derivative w.r.t. $t$)

Thus, already the step $v = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}$ is incorrect. The $\Delta$-notation (and idea) really only works if there are only linear dependences. Stick to true derivatives to avoid mistakes.